# Serving resized image files

Tags: apache-2.2, http, images

Is there an Apache module or similar that will allow me to serve images and varying sizes?

We have a a lot of images (gif, jpeg and png) that are all around 150x150, some are bigger but all are 1:1 in size.

I would like to be able to serve images like this:

http://images.ourserver.com/image/path/realimage.png?50x50
http://images.ourserver.com/image/path/realimage.png?100x100

And get back a resized version of the original file. A cache of the resized file should also be created.

This sounds like a problem that should have already been solved.

(We run currently run CentOS servers but all options will be considered.)

Answer (score 3):

I've never used it myself but I found [Apache::Imager:Resize](http://search.cpan.org/~wross/Apache-Imager-Resize-0.11/lib/Apache/Imager/Resize.pm) which seems to do what you want and has a few links to related modules.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an apache module, but it would be fairly trivial to implement using php, gd, and a very simple set of rewrite rules.

Details on that implementation would probably be best asked over on SO.